# RabbitMQ throws Shared Queue closed error

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

We have been using **RabbitMQ** as messaging service in the project. We will be pushing message into a queue and which will be received at the message consumer and will be trying to make entry into database. Once the values entered into the database we will be sending positive acknowledgement back to the **RabbitMQ** server if not we will be sending negative acknowledgement.

I have created Message Consumer as Windows service.Message has been successfully entered and well received by the message consumer(Made entry in table)but with an exception log "Shared Queue closed".

Please find the code block.

```
 while (true)
        {

            try
            {

                if (!Connection.IsOpen || !Channel.IsOpen)
                {
                  CreateConnection(existConnectionConfig, QueueName);
                  consumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(Channel);
                 consumerTag=Channel.BasicConsume(QueueName,false,consumer);      
                }

                    BasicDeliverEventArgs e = (BasicDeliverEventArgs)consumer.Queue.Dequeue();
                    IBasicProperties props = e.BasicProperties;
                    byte[] body = e.Body;
                   bool ack = onMessageReceived(body);

                    if (ack == true)
                    {
                        Channel.BasicAck(e.DeliveryTag, false);
                    }
                    else
                        Channel.BasicNack(e.DeliveryTag, false, true);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                //Logged the exception in text file where i could see the 
                //message as "Shared queue closed"
            }
        }
```

I have surfed in net too but couldn't able to what the problem. It will be helpful if anyone able to help me out.

Thanks in advance,
Selva

Comment: How many consumers on the bus in total are involved in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your question, I have experienced the same problems when my Web Client has reset the connection due to App Pool recycling or some other underlying reason the connection has been dropped that appears beyond your scope. You may need to build in a retry mechanism to cope with this.

You might want to look at [MassTransit](http://masstransit-project.com/). I have used this with RabbitMQ and it makes things a lot easier by effectively providing a management layer to RabbitMQ. MassTransit takes away the headache of retry mechanisms - see [Connection management](http://masstransit.readthedocs.org/en/master/overview/valueadd.html). It also provides a nice multi threaded concurrent consumer configuration.

This has the bonus of your implementation being more portable - you could easily change things to MSMQ should the requirement come along.